# How can i create a new oracle (10g) procedure/function from php script?

Tags: php, oracle10g

hi i am creating a project that requires oracle database in conjunction with php. i have managed to create tables, update, insert etc. everything from php script. but now, i want to create **(NOT EXECUTE, JUST CREATE)** a new **oracle procedure/function from php.** please help me.
i want **something** like this:

```
<?php 
     $conn = ocilogon('xxxx','xxxx','XE');
     $str = "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(p IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
       BEGIN
           RETURN p * 3;
       END;";
     $stid=oci_parse($conn,$str);
     oci_execute($stid); // this gives me success with compilation error.
```

what can i do?

Comment: What is the error if you query `user_| all_ | dba_errors`?

Comment: sorry sir, i don't have any idea about the command you gave since i am not very experienced in this field....but it gives me this error to be exact : Warning: oci_execute(): OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO: ORA-24344: success with compilation error

Comment: Log in to Oracle and query `user_errors` (if you are logging in as the same user that owns the function).  That will show you the specific compilation error.

Comment: the query doesn't give me any error when i try to run on Oracle. i am using "Navicat Premium" as my GUI application to run Oracle commands directly...in Navicat the query executes just fine....but in php, it gives me the error i mentioned.

Comment: btw, if i use `echo var_dump(ocierror())` it gives me `bool(false)` 

sir i am sorry if i am not being specific enough.

Comment: If the procedure fails to compile, then there will be an error in `user_errors` (or `all_errors` or `dba_errors` depending on your privileges).  You can query that table from any tool if your client API doesn't provide you the text of the error message.

Comment: ok i will try to find out by using `user_errors` 
thank you sir.